# asyncio parallelism of external library function not marked async

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I need to send requests in parallel using asyncio. The requests are sent via the function `server_time` from a library that I can't change. It's a function, not a coroutine, so can't await it, which is the challenge here.

I've been trying with the code below but it doesn't work obviously, same reason you can parallelize `await asyncio.sleep(1)` but not `time.sleep(1)`.

How do I use asyncio to parallelize this? I.e., how can I parallelize something like `time.sleep(1)` using asyncio?

```
from pybit import HTTP
import time
import asyncio

session = HTTP('https://api-testnet.bybit.com')

async def latency():
    time_1 = time.perf_counter()
    session.server_time()
    return time.perf_counter() - time_1

async def avg_latency(n_requests):
    total_time = 0
    tasks = []
    for _ in range(n_requests):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(latency()))
    for task in tasks:
        total_time += await task
    return total_time / n_requests

# First one to establish the connection. The latency improves after.
session.server_time()

latency = asyncio.run(avg_latency(10))
print(f'{1000 * latency:.2f} ms')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to run the synchronous, I/O-bound `session.server_time` function in parallel:

```
import asyncio
from pybit import HTTP
import time

session = HTTP('https://api-testnet.bybit.com')

async def latency():
   time_1 = time.perf_counter()
   loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
   await loop.run_in_executor(None, session.server_time)
   return time.perf_counter() - time_1

async def avg_latency(n_requests):
   return sum(await asyncio.gather(*[latency() for _ in range(n_requests)]))/n_requests

print(asyncior.run(avg_latency(10)))
```